# Are SSL certificates fixed to IP's within a region?

Tags: amazon-ec2, wildcard-subdomain, ssl-certificate

I need to purchase a wildcard ssl certificate.

I am looking at purchasing it from Comodo, however when I go to purchase it  there is a question asking to "select the region that you are located in". Here is the [link](http://ssl.comodo.com/wildcard-ssl-certificates.php?key5sk1=d05e3cf9f435f006d6a225a1757b8855859ccaa9&key5sk2=2128&key5sk3=1347321813000&key5sk4=2128&key5sk5=1347321821000&key5sk6=&key5sk7=1347321830000&key5sk8=1907&key5sk9=1347321835000&key6sk1=&key6sk2=FF1501&key6sk3=9&key6sk4=en-us&key6sk5=NZ&key6sk6=0&key6sk7=Google&key6sk8=1101&key6sk9=1280800&key6sk10=true&key6sk11=ea6a65e2007280cb9f577d1add6ac77a79abbac4&key6sk12=2032&key7sk1=2&key7sk2=43&key7sk3=196140&key1sk1=ors&key1sk2=Google).

I am not sure exactly why this question is asked but I am wondering if these certificates are fixed to servers hosted within the specified regions?

I am hosting on Amazon EC2 and will be hosting servers in multiple regions therefore I don't really want to be purchasing certificates for each region.

I have asked support this exact question but they will not give me a straight answer which doesn't make me very comfortable with going ahead and purchasing the certificate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SSL certificates are not based on region, neither are they linked to specific IPs. You can use them wherever you want.

However, you could be facing a third party that will ask you to buy in your currency (i.e: check their conversion rate between euro and $USD. It's... interesting).

Your CSR/CRT will have to declare your country, through the "SUBJECT: C=" part of the certificate, but this could be setted to whatever you want - and want your customer to see. For more info see [X.509](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509) specs on wikipedia.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I've ever known, SSL certificates are not restricted to use on specific IP addresses or blocks of addresses. Most likely Comodo is asking for your region for some billing purpose (e.g. if you live in Europe they may have to do some EU-specific billing). In fact, I can see that by changing the region, they change the currency in which your price is quoted (e.g. dollars for the US, pounds for the UK, euros for the EU, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

The information that they require its only for determinate where the buyer is and all, its only security porpouses... Ive got a couple of them and in each they ask you where you are from, actually at a SSL certificate you need to indicate the country by the letters of identity (USA, MEX, etc..).

The SSL certificate will work for anyone who enter at your side from any part of the world (unless you restrict the access to your web and all..)